# Using INSERT to copy from listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am allowing my users to select an item in a list box, then click a button to put the data in to its own table.

This is my code:

```
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strSQL As String

For Each varItem In Me.LettersDueList.ItemsSelected

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_OmbudsmanCompletedWorkTEST (CustomerAccountNumber, NoteTypeDescription, BusinessAreaDescription, NotePurposeCode, CSUserID, AdvisorName, Site) " _
                                    & "Values(" & Me.LettersDueList.Column(0, varItem) & ", " _
                                    & Me.LettersDueList.Column(1, varItem) & ", " _
                                    & Me.LettersDueList.Column(2, varItem) & ", " _
                                    & Me.LettersDueList.Column(3, varItem) & ", " _
                                    & Me.Text43.Value & "," _
                                    & Me.Text21.Value & "," _
                                    & Me.LettersDueList.Column(6, varItem) & ")"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Next
```

My code debugs at this line:

```
& Me.LettersDueList.Column(1, varItem) & ", " _
```

The error:

> ```
> Syntax Error (Missing Operator)
> ```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you write `debug.print Me.LettersDueList.Column(1, varItem)` before the line `strSQL = "INS...` and see what is happening in the immediate window?

Comment: Personally I prefer using `strSQL = strSQL &` on each separate line as I've had issues with the underscore character causing syntax problems before

Comment: Using debug.print produces no results in the immediate window either unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re missing the single quotes `''` around text fields, like:
`"'" & Me.LettersDueList.Column(1, varItem) & "', "`.

By the way, you should consider the `StringFormat` helper function, it will make your life a lot easier.

```
Public Function StringFormat(ByVal Item As String, ParamArray args() As Variant) As String

    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        Item = Replace(Item, "{" & idx & "}", args(idx))
    Next idx

    StringFormat = Item
End Function
```

Your SQL string would then look like this:

```
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strSQL As String

For Each varItem In Me.LettersDueList.ItemsSelected
    strSQL = StringFormat("INSERT INTO tbl_OmbudsmanCompletedWorkTEST (CustomerAccountNumber, NoteTypeDescription, BusinessAreaDescription, NotePurposeCode, CSUserID, AdvisorName, Site) " & _
                          "VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}');", _
                          Me.LettersDueList.Column(0, varItem), _
                          Me.LettersDueList.Column(1, varItem), _
                          Me.LettersDueList.Column(2, varItem), _
                          Me.LettersDueList.Column(3, varItem), _
                          Me.Text43.Value, _
                          Me.Text21.Value, _
                          Me.LettersDueList.Column(6, varItem))
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
Next
```

Just remove the single quotes `'{0}'` on numeric fields.

Nevertheless, personally I would prefer a parameterized query:

```
PARAMETERS [prm1] Text (255), [prm2] Text (255), [prm3] Text (255);
INSERT INTO YourTableName ( Field1, _Field2, Field3 )
SELECT [prm1], [prm2], [prm3];
```

...

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QueryName")
    .Parameters("[prm1]").Value = Value1
    .Parameters("[prm2]").Value = Value2
    .Parameters("[prm3]").Value = Value3
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```

---

### About the StringFormat Function

`StringFormat` is a custom helper function which mimics the `C# String.Format()` method.

The simplified version, as the one provided, accepts two parameters, a `String` and a `ParamArray()` and it returns a concatenated `String` by replacing `{0}`,`{1}, ...` with the supplied argument(s) at specified index.

So in a SQL string scenario:

```
"FirstName='" & firstName_ & "' And LastName='" & lastname_ & "'"
```

becomes:

```
"FirstName='{0}' And LastName='{1}'", firstName_, lastname_
```

You can read more about the `C# String.Format()` method here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting

The simplified version quoted above is from the *Expert Access 2007 Programming* by Rob Cooper and Michael Tucker: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Expert-Access-2007-Programming.productCd-0470174021.html

Lastly you can see the full implementation from Mat's Mug here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/a-csharpish-string-format-formatting-helper/31000#31000

Comment: Thank you for this reply - Can you explain what the strong format does? Still new to this so I am still educating myself. Thanks in advance

Comment: @dmorgan20 Added a bit of info regarding the `StringFormat` function. Hope it helps.